# Editing a display method to produce a histogram (Java)

Tags: java

I'm given this code I'm suppose to edit the display method to produce a histogram like

```
0: *************
1: ******************
2: *************
```

With the largest one scaled to 40.

Now I don't know how I'm suppose to do this properly I can introduce a for loop and a couple of print methods but I don't think that's how I'm suppose to do it and the output doesn't look too neat when I do it that way.

```
public class LastDigitDistribution

{

   private int[] counters;



   /**

    Constructs a distribution whose counters are set to zero.

  */

 public LastDigitDistribution()

  {

    counters = new int[10];

  }



  /**

     Processes values from this sequence.

     @param seq the sequence from which to obtain the values

     @param valuesToProcess the number of values to process

  */

  public void process(Sequence seq, int valuesToProcess)

  {

    for (int i = 1; i <= valuesToProcess; i++)

     {

        int value = seq.next();

        int lastDigit = value % 10;

        counters[lastDigit]++;

     }

  }

  /**

     Displays the counter values of this distribution.

  */

  public void display()

  {

     for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++)

    {

        System.out.println(i + ": " + counters[i]);

     }

  }

}
```

Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: what's your input data look like? If this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: the question and sample look very much like homework to me too.

Comment: Sorry, new on the site didn't know we were suppose to tag it as such. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Since the code (data source) and structure (invocation of display) is incomplete, I have a hint for issues in display method:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++)      {          
    System.out.print(i + ": " + counters[i] + " ");       
    for ( int j = 0 ; j < counters[i] ; j++ ) {
       System.out.print( '*' );       
    }
    System.out.println( "" );       // line feed only here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, there was a sequence class with it didn't think it was important to post that, I'm still confused to as to how I will scale the largest bar to 40?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. What determines the number of stars?

Comment: @user1069755 Find the largest number assign 40 to it, loop over all others and divide them by (largest/40) it is the same as you would do in calculation of percentage (just with 40 instead of 100).

Answer (score 0):

I would go this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counters.length; i++)      {          
    System.out.println(StringUtils.repeat("*", counters[i]));
}
```